# java, db2 . inserting dropdowns and checkbox values in same columns

Tags: java, sql

```html
//these are previous dropdown form variables
private int firstname;
private int lastname;

setters and getters for above variables

//my new checkbox form variables
private int ck1;
private int ck2;

//setters and getters 


//query to insert

insert into TEST(private int firstname, lastname, ck1, ck2)
values(?,?,?,?);

//update query 
update TEST set firstname=?, lastname=?, ck1=?, ck2=?
where id=name;

//i do not have any column ck1, ck2 in test table . i am trying to insert ck1,ck2 values in pre-existing column which are firstname, lastname (these  columns also hold values for firtname and lastname variables and now trying to insert values for ck1 and ck2 and thats where i am stuck) .
```

Guys I need some suggestions. lets say I have a table with two columns-"firstname" and "lastname" and they store values from dropdowns. Now i have a 2 checkbox and i need to store values in same columns (lastname, firstname). for saving values in same columns i have 2 form variables ("check1", "check2") with setters and getters. now i am kind a stuck, please guide me how i can store checkbox values in the same columns to dropdowns.

Comment: I'd suggest making your question more clear. I can't understand what is the exact problem

Comment: Please add some code to show what are you doing, and the error if you have.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the UPDATE statement is

```
UPDATE TEST SET firstname = value1, lastname = value2
```

if firstname and lastname are `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` enclose their values inside apostrophes like `'this'`  
and not

```
update TEST set firstname=?, lastname=?, ck1=?, ck2=?
```

Comment: provide me the logic , what needed to be done to insert 2 variable values in exiting column which has been storing other variables values

Comment: There is a lot to be done to access a database with java. You can google sqlite with java, or for android sqliteopenhelper and follow the tutorials and documentation.